# Show YTD with Week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table which shows me Weekly sales by sellers. My current query (attached) has only two columns. I want to add a third column that will entail YTD (Year to date) sales data. Can someone please provide assistance on this, what can I add to my current SQL statement?

```
select t2.Source, coalesce(t1."This Week",0) "This Week"
from sellers t2 left outer join
(select Source,min("Week") as Week, sum(Sales) "This Week"
from salesdata
where Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
group by Source, Week) t1
on t1.Source = t2.Source
```

Current Result:

```
Source            This Week

Judith              18
Thedia              64
Alfonso              0
Michael             15
Jordan               0
```

Desired Result:

```
Source            This Week             YTD

Judith              18                  100
Thedia              64                  150
Alfonso              0                  258 
Michael             15                  487 
Jordan               0                   78
```

Comment: you should also explain how you calculate ytd sales

Comment: A window function: `sum(sales) over (partition by t2.source order by week)` maybe?

Comment: date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1...this function gives me the data of passed Sunday so in this case it would be 1/1/2016 to 1/1/2017.

Comment: @Horse where should I have the SQL syntax you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the field `week` is of type `date` in your table:

```
SELECT source, week, "This Week", "YTD"
FROM (
    SELECT source, week, coalesce(sum(sales), 0) AS "This Week"
    FROM salesdata
    WHERE week = date_trunc('week', now()) - 1) sw
JOIN (
    SELECT source, coalesce(sum(sales), 0) AS "YTD"
    FROM salesdata
    WHERE date_trunc('year', week) = date_trunc('year', now()) sy USING (source);
```

Note that you do not need the `sellers` table, all information can come from the `salesdata` table.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sy"
LINE 9:     WHERE year::date = date_trunc('year', now()) sy USING (...There is something going on @ 'sy'.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how you get your date information. If `year` is an `integer`, for instance, you need to use `year = extract(year from current_time)::integer`. If you have a `timestamp` in your table then you would use `date_trunc('year', field) = date_trunc('year', current_time)`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I just have one time pertinent field and it is 'Week' and it is  a date field. The 'Week' has data for previous years.